# Using Stanford Corenlp for Chinese in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stanford-nlp

I am attempting to use coreNLP's capabilities for segmenting, POS and NER on Chinese texts. I am trying to use the [official StanfordCoreNLP python package](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/python-stanford-corenlp) on `windows 10` with `python 3.6`.

I do not know how to tell CoreNLP to work in Chinese. I have downloaded the stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27.zip file as well as the `stanford-chinese-corenlp-2018-02-27-model.jar` file from the [official corenlp website](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/). Part of the issue is that there seem to be hundreds of python wrappers for Stanford's CoreNLP,  including `nltk`, `stanfordcorenlp`, `py-corenlp`, etc.; which makes it difficult for me to find what exactly I need to do for any particular package. I currently have English working with the `corenlp` package. I suspect the solution is passing the language or the path of the Chinese .jar into the segmenter.

Code for English (from the official website):

```
import corenlp

text = "Chris wrote a simple sentence that he parsed with Stanford CoreNLP."
with corenlp.CoreNLPClient(annotators="tokenize ssplit".split()) as client:
     ann = client.annotate(text)
sentence = ann.sentence[0]
sentence.token[0].word
>>>"Chris"
```

Trying with a Chinese sentence yields a memory error for POS or NER tagging, and an encoding (I believe) error for tokenizing.

Comment: also interested

Comment: Hey echan, not sure what you're trying to do but for me an okay workaround was using the `jieba` package. It doesn't have NER tagging and the POS tagging is confusing, but it works fine. Still hoping for a fix/tutorial for CoreNLP though.

Comment: I'm mainly looking to do Chinese sentence parsing. It doesn't seem like jieba package does that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'sentence parsing'. `jieba` has the method `cut` (or `lcut`) for word tokenizing, if you want to do sentence tokenizing then you might be able to simply call `text.split` for each relevant punctuation mark, or you could try something similar with regexes.

Answer (score 0):

`corenlp-python` act as a client to the `CoreNLP Server`.
For convenience, calling the client will start a `default server`, which serves English NLP Tasks.

You can [start the server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#getting-started) by yourself, configured with Chinese support:

```
java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

When use the python client, tell it there is no need to start a `default server`:

```py
with corenlp.CoreNLPClient(
        start_server=False,
        endpoint='http://localhost:9000',
        annotators="tokenize ssplit pos".split()) as client:
  ann = client.annotate(text)
```